# Why is a request returning forbidden only in PHPUnit testing?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm having a problem with a test class in a Laravel 6 project.  The following test fails because the returned response is `403 forbidden` rather than a view.  However, I can only reproduce this in tests - in the main application it returns the view as expected.  Has anyone experienced anything similar or can see anything obviously wrong in the below?

**ProductTest.php**

```
public function testUsersCanViewTheirOwnProducts(){

        $user = Factory(User::class)->create();
        $product = Factory(Product::class)->create(['user_id'=>$user->id]);

        $this->actingAs($user);
        $response = $this->get(route('show_product',['product'=>$product->id]));

        $response->assertViewIs('products.show'); //Fails not a view (403 forbidden when response dumped)
        $response->assertViewHas('product',$product);

    }
```

Dumping `$user->id` and `$product->id` returns `1` for both as expected.

**ProductController.php**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Product::class, 'product');
    }

//...

public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view("products.show",['product'=>$product]);
    }
```

**ProductPolicy.php**

```
public function view(User $user, Product $product)
{
    return $user->id === $product->user_id;
}
```

**testing.env**

```
//identical to .env apart from
TELESCOPE_ENABLED=false
DB_DATABASE=subscribe_test
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/manage/products/{product}','ProductController@show')->middleware('auth')->name('show_product');
```

I have cleared all caches with no effect. The resource returns 403 in PHPUnit tests and 200 in the application. What am missing?

Comment: Did you added the policy to the service provider?

Comment: What auth driver are you using? You might need to specify in actingAf

Comment: @EliasSoares auto-discovered by naming convention and the default auth driver (users table). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post your route?

Comment: @EliasSoares Have added in the route.  I've got the expected behaviour (see answer) but no idea why this is happening?

Comment: Really makes no sense. I'm trying to think a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the expected response in the test by editing my `phpunit.xml` file, which it turns out was overriding my `.env.testing`.

Removing these two lines gives the expected behaviour.

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

Allowing my expected `.env.testing` to give:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_DATABASE=subscribe_test
```

However I don't see why this would fail on SQLLite?  Especially when the values for comparing the IDs both dump the expected values.

Comment: Well, this actually solved the issue for me too, but I cannot figure out why this happens only with Sqlite. Now my tests are way slower.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that SQLite is returning $user->id as an integer and $product->user_id as a string.

See here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3548